# Updating Related Data with the Entity Framework 4 in MVC 3 - ContosoUniversity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

In ContosoUniversity example from
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application
How do I display ALL the instructors for each student in the Student/Details Page. What I believe is that I need to go through the following Entities to get to the Instructors’ data:

Student (Enrollments)

Enrollment (Course)

Course (Instructors)

Instructors (Courses)

I’ve tried to use the example from the Instructors’ tab but I get stuck when I have to prepare the entity with all the Instructors.

I created a View Model:

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.ViewModels

{

```
public class StudentIndexData
```

{

```
    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get; set; } 

    public IEnumerable<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }

}
```

}

And then I started with the following new MoreDetails page from the StudentController

public ActionResult MoreDetails(System.Int32? iStID)

```
    {
        var viewModel = new StudentIndexData();
        viewModel.Students = ctxDB.ctxStudents
        .Include(i => i.Enrollments.Select(c => c.Course))
        .Where(i => i.StudentID == iStID);



        if (iStID != null)
        {
            ViewBag.StudentID = iStID;

            viewModel.Enrollments = viewModel.Students.Where(i => i.StudentID == iStID).Single().Enrollments;
        }

        HERE IS WHERE I GET STUCK I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO POPULATE THE INSTRUCTORS ENTITY. AND COURSES ALSO.

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
var std = db.Students
            .Include(s => s.Enrollments.Select(en=>en.Course))
            .Where(s => s.StudentId == id)
            .SingleOrDefault(); // or ToList() if you want fetch all students

if(std != null){

    // do your work, for example, accessing this properties:
    var a = std; // the student
    var b = std.Enrollments; // student's enrollments
    var c = std.Enrollments.First().Course; // test for access one of the enrollments's course
    var d = c.Instructors; // test for access course's instructors all

    // or project all instructors in a List:
    var instructors = new List<Instructor>();
    foreach (var enr in std.Enrollments) {
        foreach (var ins in enr.Course.Instructors) {
            if (!instructors.Contains(ins)) {
                instructors.Add(ins);
            }
         }
     } // now, the "instructors" contains all instructors associated with current user!

}else{
    // if is null, do something else
}
```

regards

> UPDATED

and if you want to test the query, replace first row, whit this one:

```
var stdquery = db.Students
                 .Include(s => s.Enrollments.Select(en=>en.Course))
                 .Where(s => s.PersonID == id);
var std = stdquery.SingleOrDefault();
```

and you'l see this sql statement on stdquery:

```
{SELECT 
[Project1].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Project1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Project1].[EnrollmentDate] AS [EnrollmentDate], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project1].[EnrollmentID] AS [EnrollmentID], 
[Project1].[CourseID] AS [CourseID], 
[Project1].[PersonID1] AS [PersonID1], 
[Project1].[Grade] AS [Grade], 
[Project1].[CourseID1] AS [CourseID1], 
[Project1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Project1].[Credits] AS [Credits], 
[Project1].[DepartmentID] AS [DepartmentID]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], 
    [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent1].[EnrollmentDate] AS [EnrollmentDate], 
    '0X0X' AS [C1], 
    [Join1].[EnrollmentID] AS [EnrollmentID], 
    [Join1].[CourseID1] AS [CourseID], 
    [Join1].[PersonID] AS [PersonID1], 
    [Join1].[Grade] AS [Grade], 
    [Join1].[CourseID2] AS [CourseID1], 
    [Join1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Join1].[Credits] AS [Credits], 
    [Join1].[DepartmentID] AS [DepartmentID], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join1].[EnrollmentID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM  [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[EnrollmentID] AS [EnrollmentID], [Extent2].[CourseID] AS [CourseID1], [Extent2].[PersonID] AS [PersonID], [Extent2].[Grade] AS [Grade], [Extent3].[CourseID] AS [CourseID2], [Extent3].[Title] AS [Title], [Extent3].[Credits] AS [Credits], [Extent3].[DepartmentID] AS [DepartmentID]
        FROM  [dbo].[Enrollments] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Courses] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[CourseID] = [Extent3].[CourseID] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[PersonID] = [Join1].[PersonID]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = 'Student') AND ([Extent1].[PersonID] = @p__linq__0)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[PersonID] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC}
```

Comment: Javad, Thank you very much - it worked. The only thing is that I needed all the instructors together with the relationship with the course (as entity?) so in the view I can have a table with the student's courses and with the corresponding instructors. See below I would assume that will help when generating the view in the foreach loop. Thank you in advance. Course |Department |Instructors 1050 - Chemistry |Engineering |Fakhouri,Fadi and Abercrombie,Kim 4022 - Microeconomics |Economics |Harui,Roger 4041 - Macroeconomics |Economics |Harui,Roger

Comment: for ONE student or without student-association? hmm, my English is not good ): so you want fetch courses (and its dependencies) for ONE student or all courses in db with out any filter?

Comment: also, if an answer is useful or help you, vote it up please :) thank you dear Paul